# How to populate a zero for NA based on presence of a value in a different row - R

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have a df as produced below. The data frame shows the number of captures and recaptures per site for each visit. However each site and capture type were not visited an equal number of times. So simply converting all NAs to zeros does not make sense. What I want is to convert NAs to zeros for sites with recaptures were capture data is present.

For example site "admin_pond" was visited 3 times with capture type "new", having captures each time. For "admin_pond" capture type "recapture", only visit_3 had recaptures. So for visit_1 and visit_2 for "admin_pond"/"recapture" I would like to populate the NAs with a zero. But still keeping visit_4, visit_5, and visit_6 as NAs for "admin_pond"/"recapture". How would I do this for all sites and recapture observations?

[image: df]

data

```
data <- structure(list(site = c("wood_lab_pond", "phelps_pond", "admin_pond", 
"rv_pond", "admin_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "rv_pond", "tuttle_pond", 
"tuttle_pond", "vorisek_pond", "vorisek_pond", "phelps_pond"), 
    capture_type = c("new", "new", "new", "new", "recapture", 
    "recapture", "recapture", "new", "recapture", "new", "recapture", 
    "recapture"), visit_1 = c(2L, 4L, 9L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 15L, 
    NA, 14L, NA, NA), visit_2 = c(4L, 3L, 15L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, 
    12L, 10L, 4L, 9L, NA), visit_3 = c(1L, 6L, 11L, 4L, 9L, 2L, 
    1L, 39L, NA, NA, NA, NA), visit_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 13L, NA, 
    NA, NA, 21L, 10L, NA, NA, NA), visit_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, 27L, 
    NA, NA, 2L, 27L, 2L, NA, NA, NA), visit_6 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    11L, NA, NA, NA, 19L, 1L, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can be easily solved with {tidyverse}.
I would do something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data %>% 
  group_by(site) %>% 
  arrange(site, capture_type) %>% # It is not required
  mutate(across(contains("visit"), 
                ~ifelse(is.na(.) &
                          !is.na(lag(.)), 0, .)))
```

This code returns the [following dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh2JS.png)

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that each site has exactly 2 rows, one `new` and 1 `recapture`:

```
data |>
  arrange(site, capture_type) |>
  mutate(
    across(starts_with("visit"),
      \(x) coalesce(x, ifelse(!is.na(lag(x, default = 0)), 0, NA_integer_))
    ),
    .by = site
  )
# # A tibble: 12 × 8
#    site          capture_type visit_1 visit_2 visit_3 visit_4 visit_5 visit_6
#    <chr>         <chr>          <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1 admin_pond    new                9      15      11      NA      NA      NA
#  2 admin_pond    recapture          0       0       9      NA      NA      NA
#  3 phelps_pond   new                4       3       6      NA      NA      NA
#  4 phelps_pond   recapture          0       0       0      NA      NA      NA
#  5 rv_pond       new                1       7       4      13      27      11
#  6 rv_pond       recapture          0       0       1       0       2       0
#  7 tuttle_pond   new               15      12      39      21      27      19
#  8 tuttle_pond   recapture          0      10       0      10       2       1
#  9 vorisek_pond  new               14       4      NA      NA      NA      NA
# 10 vorisek_pond  recapture          0       9      NA      NA      NA      NA
# 11 wood_lab_pond new                2       4       1      NA      NA      NA
# 12 wood_lab_pond recapture          0       0       2      NA      NA      NA
```